# Why I get error "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

I've read about `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context` error but I don't understand why I get it in my case (line `return new CommandParser1(command);`)?. I just create instance of class. That's all. What is the problem?

```
public class ProtocolUtility {

    public static CommandParser createParser(String command) throws Exception {           
        switch (command) {
            case COMMAND_1:
                return new CommandParser1(command);                  
            case COMMAND_2:
               return new CommandParser2(command);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

   public abstract class CommandParser {

       protected String command;

       public String getCommand() {
          return command;
       }       
   }

   public  class CommandParser1 extends CommandParser {       
       public CommandParser1 (String command){
           //...
       }       
   }

   public  class CommandParser2 extends CommandParser {      
       public CommandParser2 (String command)  {
           //...
       }      
   }
```

}

Comment: `public static CommandParser createParser(String command) throws Exception {           
        switch (command) {`
How can you have switch with a `String`?

Comment: @BharatSinha: http://java.dzone.com/articles/new-java-7-feature-string - note that Java 7 is more than year old by now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CommandParser` is an *inner class* which means it needs an instance of outer class (`ProtocolUtility`) to be created. Change its declaration to:

```
public static abstract class CommandParser {
```

Alternatively declare `CommandParser` in a separate `.java` file.

Your code would also work if `createParser()` wasn't `static` as in this case an instance of `ProtocolUtility` you are currently in would be used as an outer instance.

Answer (score 1):

When `createParser` is called in a static way (i.e., `ProtocolUtility.createParser(...)`) you can't instantiate objects from classes that are defined inside `ProtocolUtility` as that would require you to have an instance of that class (which you don't have). This can be fixed by also making the inner classes `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Because CommandParser1() is not static. You need an instance of CommandParser1 to call CommandParser1() or to define it as static.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `Static method` **canNOT access** a `Non-static method or variable.`

Your code `return new CommandParser1(command);`  in **inside static method** `public static` `CommandParser createParser(String command)`, so **thats causing the error.**

**2.** And as you are trying to access `CommandParser1(command)` which is an `inner class` from  `class ProtocolUtility` **which is its** `outer class`, **YOU CAN DIRECTLY ACCESS IT AS YOU ARE DOING IT NOW**
But suppose, when you are trying to make an **access to it from outside** the `ProtocolUtility class`, then you need to **Create an Outer class instance to access this inner class method.**

Comment: Please never mind the faux-pas of using caps and bold. What matters is the content; the commenter has explained the issue correctly to my estimation.

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel if appearance is more important to you than the technical correctness of the answer, better go join some Management field.